# Why I cannot specify "-f origin main" in the "Push options" textbox of TortoiseGit push window?

Tags: git, tortoise-git

I have some mismatch between the local and remote `main` branches.
So I want to forcibly reset the `main` branch on the remote named `origin`.

With git command line, I can do it with:

```
git checkout main
git reset --hard <some hash> (now the local and remote main branches are different)
git push -f origin main
```

I want to do the same with the TortoiseGit Push window like below:

[image]

But it failed with below error message saying that I need to pull first.

[image]

**Could anyone tell me why the "Push options" textbox doesn't work as the command line?**

I checked the TortoiseGit [official doc](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-push.html) about the push window. The screenshot is like below. It even doesn't have a "Push option" input box...
[image]

Comment: Why not simply tick "known changes" and be done with it? Or, if you truly need it, "unknown changes".

Comment: @DanielB Yes. That can work. I am just thinking that the `Push option` ***should*** be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The push dialog in TortoiseGit has the "force" option.

You need the check the "known changes" or "unknown changes" chechboxes in the line "Force: May discard":

[image: Push Dialog]

The "known changes" implies the "force-with-lease" and "unkown changes" just issues the plain old "--force" option.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-push.html

With TortoiseGit >= 2.13 the checkbox is renamed but still at the very same position.